# What well known figures have perimeter equal to $e$

Tags: geometry

what figures that are common knowledge have perimeter equal to $e$ in a similar manner like circle have $\pi$? they can be smooth im not interested in answers like the triangle of $\frac{e}{3}$ because i want to define $e$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde first it is not about a perimeter. bu see that the $1$ circles area equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$. what are the names of that figures?

Comment: You can also take the perimeter instead the area for an geometric figure under a function like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. But basically the duplicate is saying that this is not "defining $e$", but rather "recognizing" it. I think the answer to your request is negative. The usual definitions for $e$ are much better. (Or at least, you should use hyperbolic geometry instead of Euclidean one.)

Comment: It is **conjectured** that $e$ is not a "period".  That is, $e$ is not an integral of an algebraic function over an algebraic domain.  So your figure (if it exists) must be transcendental.